# Move shape to the right after a certain amount of time

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to make the objects that I have displayed which is two triangles and a line (which resembles a face) move 5 times to the right each second when the ESC key is pressed. I tried to output the counter (i) to see if it goes through the for loop and it does show up. However, the objects themselves don't move. How can I resolve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

void display();
void facemove(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void moveright(int value);

//y axis of eyes
float eyelower = 0.25f;
float eyeupper = 0.50f;

//left eye
float leftx1 = -0.50f;
float leftx2 = -0.10f;
float leftx3 = -0.30f;

//right eye
float rightx1 = 0.10f;
float rightx2 = 0.50f;
float rightx3 = 0.30f;

//mouth
float mouthx1 = -0.15f;
float mouthx2 = 0.15f;
float mouthy1 = 0.0f;

//default color for left eye
int lrdefault = 255;
int lgdefault = 215;
int lbdefault = 0;

//default color for right eye
int rrdefault = 255;
int rgdefault = 215;
int rbdefault = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("My First Program");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(facemove);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3ub(0,102,0);
    glVertex2f(-0.98f, -0.98f);
    glVertex2f(-0.98f, 0.98f);
    glVertex2f(0.98f, 0.98f);
    glVertex2f(0.98f, -0.98f);
    glEnd();
    
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub(lrdefault, lgdefault, lbdefault);
    glVertex2f(leftx1, eyelower);
    glVertex2f(leftx2, eyelower);
    glVertex2f(leftx3, eyeupper);
    glEnd();
    
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub(rrdefault, rgdefault, rbdefault);
    glVertex2f(rightx1, eyelower);
    glVertex2f(rightx2, eyelower);
    glVertex2f(rightx3, eyeupper);
    glEnd();
      
    glColor3ub(255, 215, 0);
    glLineWidth(5.0f);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(mouthx1,mouthy1);
    glVertex2f(mouthx2, mouthy1);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void facemove(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    switch(key){
        case 27:
            glutTimerFunc(5000, moveright, 5);  
        break;
        
        default:
        //insert here
        break;
        
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    }
}


void moveright(int value){
    int timer = value;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        leftx1 += .09f;
        leftx2 += .09f;
        leftx3 += .09f;
        rightx1 += .09f;
        rightx2 += .09f;
        rightx3 += .09f;
        eyelower += .09f;
        eyeupper += .09f;
        mouthx1 += .09f;
        mouthx2 += .09f;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        cout<< i;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    glutDestroyWindow(1);
}
```

Comment: So should I just remove the glutDestroyWindow() call?

Comment: What I wanted to do is let's say move the x values by 0.09 then redisplay then move again by 0.09 until I have done it for 5 times.